# How can I check if a checkbox is NOT checked

Tags: php, checkbox

I need to check whether checkbox is checked or not. Normally I would do it like this:

```
<?php
    $checked = isset($_POST['checkbox']);
?>
```

But I don't know what is the name. More at screenshot (I'm using Laravel 4).

[Screenshot](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/v/t35.0-12/10272413_622422667840235_792991781_o.jpg?oh=886da8f366c263baa15741cc4f4561c6&oe=534F362A&__gda__=1397703964_90606f682649fe16dfd18c8dcbd19e55)

Comment: Checkboxes are only set in the $_POST array if they are checked. If they are not checked, they just don't exist in $_POST.

Comment: I thnk you should find the name by checking the Checkbox' Name in Browser Source view, or Press F12 on chrome or any browser to see the name and then put same check you used previously.

Comment: You need to keep a record of what checkboxes the page contains, and match them against what you receive - if you don't receive one, it's not checked. Unfortunately if you don't already know the names you're stuck.

Comment: I guess the next question is then: Why don't you know what the name of the checkbox is? Is it an id? Do you not have control over the form to change it?

Comment: I get names of fields from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposedly you should know what the list of checkboxes is/was that you asked the user to check. Checked checkboxes are submitted to the server, unchecked ones aren't. You can calculate the difference between these two lists.

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't. The data for unchecked checkboxes are not send to the server.

You could do a workaround with javascript where the JS appends some hidden fields before submit with the nonchecked boxes

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery, and you know the id of the checkbox,
then, you can detect with following code:

```
var isChecked = $("#cbId").is(":checked");
```

Comment: That doenst answer the question. He didnt want the unchecked boxes in client side but on server side.

Comment: If you dont know your checkboxes? Jep - that would be bad design^^

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ( ! isset($_POST['checkbox_name']))
{
    "Not checked";
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't know what is the name

Comment: So if you don't know the name of it then there is no way to know. How can you imagine this?

Comment: I get names of fields from database.

Answer (score 0):

If checkbox didn't check - you will not have this variable in $_REQUEST.

```
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="ch2"/>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="ch3"/>
<input type="submit" name="Post" value="Post">
</form>
```

When you click on "Post". In backend you'll see:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['ch1']))
    echo 'ch1 is checked!';
if(isset($_REQUEST['ch2']))
    echo 'ch2 is checked!';
if(isset($_REQUEST['ch3']))
    echo 'ch3 is checked!';
?>
```

In my case you'll see: "ch3 is checked!".

Comment: OP said he does not know the name of checkbox